# the speed of read and write system call on shared memory object in comparison with one of memcpy

Tags: c++, shared-memory, file-descriptor, epoll

I' using shared memory (with semaphore) for communicating between two processes:
Fist, I open shared memory object using the call:

```
int fd = shm_open("name") [http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open]
```

Second, I map this shared mem object into my adress space using call:

```
void* ptr = mmap(..fd..) [http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap2]
```

However, I want to use EPOLL in conjunction with shared memory file descriptor==> I don't use mmap anymore, and instead, using EPOLL for monitoring, and then add, write function for direct access to shared memory using fd (shared memmory file descriptor)

My question is that: how is the speed of direct reading and writing on shared memory object in comparison with memcpy on pointer returned by mmap?

```
read(fd, buffer) vs memcpy(des, source, size) //???
```

Hope to see your answer! Thanks!

Comment: Why not do some profiling and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

`read` is a syscall and implies a privilege transition which implies address space manipulation (MMU) and then the kernel will call `memcpy` from your provided buffer to the destination address. It basically does the same thing you would do (call `memcpy`) but adding 2 expensive operations (privilege transitions) and a cheap one (finding the destination address).

We can conclude that the `read`/`write` is very likely to be slower.